# how to get guid in list definition

Tags: list, list-definition, guid

I have noticed that many examples of internet which show creating the list definition have a GUID in the id of the field. How is this ID got? e.x.

Where is this GUID got from?

Comment: Oh really, I didn' know that It was so simple. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Usually in Visual Studio; Tools -> Generate GUID

Answer (score 0):

Go to the list settings page. Right click on "Title, description and navigation" and copy the URL. Paste that into notepad and copy everything after "List=" in the string. That's your URL Encoded GUID for the list. All you need to do is decode it here http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php

source: [Get a SharePoint List GUID from the Browser](http://weblogs.asp.net/jimjackson/archive/2008/02/11/get-a-sharepoint-list-guid-from-the-browser.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> While each generated GUID is not guaranteed to be unique, the total
>   number of unique keys (2^128 or 3.4×10^38) is so large that the
>   probability of the same number being generated twice is very small.
>   For example, consider the observable universe, which contains about
>   5×10^22 stars; every star could then have 6.8×10^15 universally unique
>   GUIDs.

For more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time